# Image retrieval through a multibeam imaging sonar

Tags: auv, sonar

I would like to know if anyone here has used the Blueview SDK (Linux) for retrieval of images from the pings obtained by a multibeam sonar (P450, P900, etc.) ?
If so, I'd like to know why would anyone get a *null head* when I trying to retrieve the head (eventually for the pings to be converted to an image) using the `BVT_GetHead()` method. My snippet for retrieving the image from a `.son` file (some_son_data.son) is given below:

```
int main() {
    BVTSonar son = BVTSonar_Create();
    BVTSonar_Open(son, "FILE", "some_son_data.son");

    if (NULL != son) cout << "son not null" << endl;
    BVTHead head = NULL ;
    BVTSonar_GetHead(son, 0, &head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation on these functions, even a header file (".h" file) with the declaration for BVTSonar_GetHead() ? http://pastebin.com/rrq35rQB isn't exactly a reliable source.

Comment: Is maybe "some_son_data.son" a zero-byte file or otherwise not in the format BVTSonar_GetHead() expects? Is maybe "some_son_data.son" in some other directory that this program can't "see"? Does the file "some_son_data.son" even exist?

Answer (score 1):

We are using the P900 multibeam sonar.

So far our interface hasn't any problem. But we requested a new version of the library from teledyne which works now in our case.

```
sonar = new BVTSDK::Sonar();
head = new BVTSDK::Head();
int ret = sonar->Open("NET", hostAddress);
 //error handling
ret = sonar->GetHead(1, head);
//again error handling
```

I will ask wether we can publish our interface within the next weeks.